# Yesod Persistent - How to compare Day to UTCTime? (How to convert them?)

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent

I have a value of type `UTCTime` representing the current time, and other value of type `Day` which I would like to know if is greater or equal than the current time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `UTCTime` is composed of a `Day` (`utctDay`) and the number of seconds since midnight (`utctDayTime`). Here's a GHCi session showing how to access the day:

```
ghci > import Data.Time
ghci > time <- getCurrentTime
ghci > :t time
time :: UTCTime
ghci > utctDay time
2016-04-30
ghci > :t utctDay time
utctDay time :: Day
```

Once you have access to the `Day`, you can use standard comparison functions (`>`, `>=` `==`, `<` and `<=`):

```
ghci > t1 <- getCurrentTime
ghci > t2 <- getCurrentTime
ghci > t1
2016-04-30 21:59:06.808488 UTC
ghci > t2
2016-04-30 21:59:11.920389 UTC
ghci > (utctDay t1) >= (utctDay t2)
True
```

You might also want to check out [the Haddocks for `UTCTime`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.14/time-1.5.0.1/Data-Time-Clock.html#t:UTCTime).